# Ionic 3 - getRootNav is deprecated - trying to setRoot without tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When I am in a tabs view and I setRoot (to the login page), the bottom tabs still persist.
I found a fix for it using:

```
this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);
```

But this gives me the following warning in console:

```
app.js:195 (getRootNav) is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Use getRootNavById instead.
```

What is the best approach here ?
I tried `getRootNavById`, but this does not have `.setRoot`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire routing is changed in ionic v4 which is the next major release. It will use angular router according to their [beta docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration/#navigation). If you are using ionic version 3, you can continue to use

```
this.app.getRootNav()
```

Migration to ionic v4 (the next major release) will probably involve an overhaul of entire navigation code.

A related discussion [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getrootnav-deprecated-use-getrootnavbyid-whats-the-value-of-the-root-nav-id/96271/43) and [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-site/issues/1197)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

`this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);`

Or this

`this.app.getRootNavs()[0].setRoot(LoginPage);`

Or this

`rootPage: any = LoginPage;`

`const root =  this.app.getRootNavs()[0];`

`root.popToRoot();`

`this.rootPage = LoginPage;`